# If we heat any gas, will it emit photons?

Tags: visible-light, photons

If we heat up any gas (let’s say hydrogen), will it emit photons? And does this mean, if we freeze it, it absorbs photons, am i right?

Comment: Why would a gas emit photon? what kind of nature of gas you have in mind? Are talking about ionization energy?what kind of system you are assuming?, it look a very incomplete question, without the proper information regarding question how can you expect a better answer?

Comment: As long as it's above 0 K it will emit photons. And also absorb photons at the same time.

Comment: Heat itself is photon

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes. All matter emits light when heated because of incandescence, but they do not absorb light when cooled.

Everything that has any heat in it emits light if it is above absolute zero, and the wavelength of this light is inversely proportional to its heat. This is the reason why we can see body heat on infrared cameras. Our bodies are just the right temperature to emit infrared light that has too long of wavelengths for us to see with our own eyes but can be picked up by cameras. All forms of matter emit light, but when heated hot enough, it will emit light with just the right amount to be seen by us. This is why a burning stove or molten metal will glow red. Because it has just the right temperature to emit red light (which is the lowest wavelength of visible light and therefore the lowest temperature to emit visible light.). Theoretically though, if something is heated enough, it can emit any wavelength of light including green, blue, and even purple though it would take about 71,000 degrees Fahrenheit for something to glow purple.

For gasses, the same thing is true. This can be seen in videos of people farting on infrared cameras. The reason it is hard to see gas glow is that the hotter the gas gets, the less dense it becomes, and so a buoyant force is acted upon it and it quickly mixes with cooler air.

As for if something cold doesn't absorb light, no it doesn't absorb light any more than a material that is warmer. Technically everything absorbs light when its hit by photons, but the temperature does not affect that. The reason for that is that Celcius and Fahrenheit are not absolute. Only Kelvin is absolute. For example, something that is -20c is 253.15K. No matter how many degrees below zero something gets in Celcius, it will always yield a positive temperature in Kelvin. That is because you can't have negative heat. Everything above absolute zero has some amount of heat, and because it has heat, instead of absorbing light, it emits light of a lower wavelength.

My name is Erik Low, and thank you for coming to my Ted Talk. :)

Comment: If i freeze hydrogen gas and make it solid, will it not absorb any photon?

Comment: @user248881 maybe superfluid helium near 0° K, solid hydrogen has nothing special, temperature will be always above 0° K.

Comment: @Erik Low  anyway I have a doubt, what if I put a gas A inside a container with a gas B. and B is hotter than A. the heat should be transmitted from B to A. but will A continue to emit photons because temperature is above zero? I guess in this case A will absorb more photons than emitted, isn't it?

Comment: @Erik Low sorry I didn't understand. I reposted the comments because of mistyping.

Comment: @StefanoBalzarotti What happens is with any substance, photons are absorbed at any temperature. When a gas or any substance changes temperature, no more or less photons are absorbed because the temperature doesn't affect the number of photons. All the temperature effects is the energy/wavelength of photons being emmited.

Comment: @user248881 why was my answer unaccepted?

Comment: @Erik Low Because you didn’t replied to my second question regarding to the main question. Sorry for my little understanding, but i asked you second question under your answer to my main question because i have a doubt in my mind and i wanted to clear it.

Comment: @user248881 Oh my bad. I thought Stefano answered it. I wouldn't know about superfluid helium, so I assumed he was right. Yeah, I said in the original answer that temperature has no effect on how many photons are absorbed. Freezing hydrogen will have no effect on it absorbing photons. If you have any more questions about this feel free to ask me

Comment: @Erik Low I hope you’re pretty sure on your answer because on first page of this article (http://www.as.utexas.edu/astronomy/education/fall08/lacy/secure/class13a.pdf), it says cool objects (whether they are gas or solid) can absorbs some light passing though it.

Comment: @user248881 Oh I see. that causes some confusion. I can go deeper into it if you want. It has to do with electron orbitals. So as you probably know, electrons are found in orbitals around a nucleus, and there are multiple orbitals higher up, and higher up an orbit, the higher energy it is. The lowest energy an atom can have is when all electrons are in its ground state meaning that all electrons are in the lowest level they can be. Electrons can be excited and brought to a higher energy level by absorbing photons or collisions (heat), the thing is that electrons can only be excited by...

Comment: ...specific wavelengths of light that will excite them to specific orbitals higher than them. But the higher the orbital, the more energy the electron has, but in higher orbits, electrons are unstable and will want to release that energy by going into a lower orbital. But when it goes into a lower orbital, where does the energy go? Well, it's released as light with specific wavelengths. If an electron by chance jumps from the orbital that it was exited to, to the one it was originally excited from, it will release that exact same wavelength but it will release other exact wavelengths...

Comment: @Erik Low You mean an electron can be excited and brought to a higher energy orbital either by absorbing photons or by collisions. Now when you say collision, do you refer to collision between electrons of a single atom? And for this collision do we have to provide heat to an atom of any element.

Comment: on which orbital it jumps down to. The more orbital levels jumped down in one jump, the higher the energy photon, and this shorter wavelength light is released. Also, an excited electron doesn't always have to jump from a higher orbital to the ground state, it will randomly jump to lower orbitals randomly releasing different wavelengths. Other than being excited by absorbing light, it can also be excited by heat. When 2 particles collide, which collision are proportional to heat, some of the energy gets absorbed by the electrons which cause them to jump to higher orbitals. When ...

Comment: Collisions between different atoms are what excite electrons, and the amount of collisions is proportional to the amount of heat in a system

Comment: ...the temperature is increased, more electrons are excited because of collisions, and electrons will get to higher orbitals, but since the higher the orbital, the more unstable it is, the electrons will take higher jumps to get to a lower orbital. thus giving off higher energy wavelengths. Note: a jump from high energy to another high energy orbital, it releases about as much energy as a low to a low energy jump. Now the reason I say that high-temperature atoms absorb as many photons as low-temperature atoms is that in a high-temperature atom, there are many electrons moving around in there..

Comment: ...so there are more electrons in higher energy states, but since a high, to similarly high-level jump takes and gives energy as a low to similarly low-level orbital, a photon with any energy level can be used to be absorbed into high energy electron or into a low energy one. The reason that that paper says that a cool atom can absorb photons is that its easier to understand if you think about it as all or most electrons in a ground state instead of the chaos of high-temperature atoms. Ps. that probably was confusing because I'm tired. Feel free to ask questions for clarification.

Comment: @Eric Low When we heat any element (let’s say an iron rod), will it cause vibration of it’s atoms or will it cause collision of it’s atoms?

Comment: So heat itself is proportional to the average kinetic energy of the individual atoms. and since KE=mV^2, that is the higher Kinetic energy the faster the individual elements are moving around in random directions, and the faster they move the more they collide with each other. In a gas, elements move freely, and that why higher temperature gas expands, because it moves away more. But in solids, because of intermolecular forces movement is restricted, so molecules do vibrate and collide with each other because of vibrations, but it doesn't move around freely like in gas

Comment: @Erik Low Thank you very much for teaching me in depth! I want to give you 9 out of 10.

Comment: @user248881 lol np